# trying to make a redirect after a certain date in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make a my index.html file redirect o another html file after i reach a certain date and time (noob here)

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        var currentdate = new Date();
        var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth()         + 1) +
        "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " +
        currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
        currentdate.getMinutes();

        var dateAfter = new Date('2023-08-5T00:00:00');

        if (currentdate > dateAfter) // Datum omschakeling
{
        location.href = "redirect.html";
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And i should go to redirect.html but its not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dateAfter` is invalid.

change

```
var dateAfter = new Date('2023-08-5T00:00:00');
```

to

```
var dateAfter = new Date('2023-08-05T00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add window object:

```
window.location.href = "YourPathFile";
```

Comment: That makes no difference.

Comment: That is because `window` is a global element. Since no variable named "location" exists in scope, js will find it at the global window level. So `window.location.href` is the same as `location.href` in this case. But as I mentioned above, the issue was in the date format.